# rails rspec expects fails for custom validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I get this error when running my rspec expects with custom validators.

```
expect {@ua.save!}.to  raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,'Validation failed: This question is no longer active')
```

fails with

```
expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid with "Validation failed: This question is no longer active", got #<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: This question is no longer active.> with backtrace:
```

This only seems to be problem with my custom validations. 
See this model:

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  validate :questionIsActive?

  private

  def questionIsActive?
    errors.add(:base, "This question is no longer active.") if !self.question.is_active?
  end
end
```

Using:
Rails 3.2.11
Rspec-rails 2.12.2

Comment: Binding your tests to a validation message, in the above manner, isn't a good idea. Why? If you change the text for the validation message in the future it will cause the test to break. If you were to bind it to the I18n message that would be better. Or, if you don't want to bind it to the message at all; you can instead write: raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Comment: For convention's sake, you'd better name the custom validation method `question_is_active` (or `active_question`). Predicate methods are meant for those that return boolean values, and snake_case is more popular than camelCase in Ruby.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a typo. Add a period to your string:

```
expect {@ua.save!}.to  raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,'Validation failed: This question is no longer active.')
```

Note: you currently have in your expectation:

'Validation failed: This question is no longer active'

but need:

'Validation failed: This question is no longer active.'

so that it matches your validation string:

'This question is no longer active.'

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious.  Thanks